# Error message when I run install.packages("tidyverse")

Tags: r

Please I need help with this. When I run install package for the `tidyverse`:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

I get this message:

```
also installing the dependencies ‘colorspace’, ‘sys’, ‘bit’, ‘ps’, ‘sass’, ‘cachem’, ‘memoise’, ‘base64enc’, ‘fastmap’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘rappdirs’, ‘rematch’, ‘askpass’, ‘bit64’, ‘prettyunits’, ‘processx’, ‘evaluate’, ‘highr’, ‘yaml’, ‘xfun’, ‘bslib’, ‘htmltools’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘tinytex’, ‘backports’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘generics’, ‘glue’, ‘assertthat’, ‘blob’, ‘DBI’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘R6’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘withr’, ‘data.table’, ‘digest’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘scales’, ‘gargle’, ‘uuid’, ‘cellranger’, ‘curl’, ‘ids’, ‘rematch2’, ‘cpp11’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘fansi’, ‘utf8’, ‘clipr’, ‘vroom’, ‘tzdb’, ‘progress’, ‘callr’, ‘fs’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘selectr’, ‘stringi’, ‘broom’, ‘cli’, ‘crayon’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘forcats’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lubridate’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘purrr’, ‘readr’, ‘readxl’, ‘reprex’, ‘rlang’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘rvest’, ‘stringr’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘xml2’

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
dplyr  1.0.9 1.0.10              TRUE
```

Comment: This isn't an error message. These are all the packages that are being installed when you install tidyverse.

Comment: When the question pops up about source being a later version, it is easier just to say NO.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for a duplicate on Stack Overflow and can't find one, so:

This is not an error message.  The key line is

> There is a binary version available but the source version is later

At this point R pauses and asks whether you want to try installing from source: **it is simplest and easiest to say "no"** (typing "n" should work). The only drawback is that you will get a *slightly* older version of the package installed. If you say "yes" (or "y" or "Y"), R will try to install from source, which will (1) not work unless you have development tools installed, (2) take a little bit longer (but it will provide you with the most recent version of the package).